# Using beautifulsoup how do I remove a single class from an element with multiple classes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to remove a single class name from an element that has multiple class names, something like this:

```
<li class="name1 name2 name3">
    <a href="http://www.somelink.com">link</a>
</li>
```

I can use beautifulsoup to remove classes in the following way:

```
soup.find(class_="name3")["class"] = ""
```

But this removes all classes not only the class that I want to lose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your html, you can see,

```
 print soup.find(class_="name3").attrs
 {'class': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']}
```

So, `soup.find(class_="name3")['class']` returns nothing but a list. And you can remove element from it as you can remove elements from list. like,

```
soup.find(class_="name3")["class"].remove('name1')
```

This will remove the class that you want to lose.

Comment: Yeah, that was actually an easy and elegant fix, thanks. I'm still a bit of a python noob.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generator expression to rebuild the class names you want to keep

```
s = 'name1 name2 name3'
s = ' '.join(i for i in s.split() if i != 'name3')

>>> s
'name1 name2'
```